# installing kubernetes on coreos with rkt and automated script

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, rkt

I'm trying to install kuberentes with rkt on my real (not virtual) coreos servers at home using the scripts at https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/tree/master/multi-node/generic and I have some questions.

1. my etcd2 is using tls keys, I can't see anywhere in the script where I can define where the certificates are located.
2. can I supply a domain instead of IP for `ADVERTISE_IP` and `CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT` ?
3. when I tried to install kubernetes manually I  needed start the rkt service api. it doesn't state in the documents that it needed here, does it mean that I don't need it if I use these scripts? or is it just something that's missing in the documents?

thanks!

## update

Rob thank you so much for your response. I wasn't clear enough regarding etcd2. I already have etcd2 tls installed and properly configured on my coreos servers. so I configured my etcd servers in the controller-install.sh file:

```
export ETCD_ENDPOINTS="https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379,https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2379"
```

but when I run the `controller-install.sh` script, it returns and repeat the following output:

```
Waiting for etcd...
Trying: https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379
Trying: https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2379
Trying: https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379
Trying: https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2379
...
```

so I was guessing it's because i didn't define etcd related tls certificates in the controller script and that is why it stuck in that faze.

on my macbook pro laptop I have the following alias configured:

```
alias myetcdctl="~/apps/etcd-v3.0.8-darwin-amd64/etcdctl --endpoint=https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379 --ca-file=/Users/ufk/Projects/coreos/tux-in/etcd/certs/certs-names/ca.pem --cert-file=/Users/ufk/Projects/coreos/tux-in/etcd/certs/certs-names/etcd1.pem --key-file=/Users/ufk/Projects/coreos/tux-in/etcd/certs/certs-names/etcd1-key.pem  --timeout=10s"
```

so when I run `myetcdctl member list` I get:

```
8832ce6a269a7dac: name=ccff826d5f564c67abf35467306f80a0 peerURLs=https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2380 clientURLs=https://coreos-3.tux-in.com:2379 isLeader=true
a2c0ac9708ef90fc: name=dc38bc8f20e64940b260d3f7b260430d peerURLs=https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2380 clientURLs=https://coreos-2.tux-in.com:2379 isLeader=false
```

so I'm guessing that I don't really have a problem there.

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Yep, if you expect to see 2 etcd instances there, I think you're good to go

Comment: @Rob - I'm good to go? It's stuck at waiting for etcd. How can kubernetes  know to connect to etcd without specifying the test certificates? I assume that is why it's stuck there.

Comment: You need to specify those flags on the kubelet. The easiest way is to use a drop-in. Here are some docs: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html#override-only-specific-option. `RKT_OPTS` with the set of flags required for etcd that will get passed into the kubelet wrapper.

Comment: @Rob - so in conclusion I was right? The automated controller installation script is missing the ETCD tls certificates location configuration and that is why the script fails? I need to modify the script do add the dropin configuration to kubelet in order for the installation script to complete installing successfully?

Comment: @Rob - I was right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my etcd2 is using tls keys, I can't see anywhere in the script where I can define where the certificates are located.

These scripts don't start an etcd server. You will need to set one up manually and will be able to use TLS and as many nodes as you would like. This isn't clear in the current form of the document, I will attempt a PR to fix.

> can I supply a domain instead of IP for ADVERTISE_IP and CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT ?

Only CONTROLLER_ENDPOINT be a domain name.

> when I tried to install kubernetes manually I needed start the rkt service api. it doesn't state in the documents that it needed here, does it mean that I don't need it if I use these scripts? or is it just something that's missing in the documents?

These scripts include/start the rkt API service. As you can see below, it also has a Restart parameter set [(source)](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/blob/master/multi-node/generic/worker-install.sh#L141):

```
[Unit]
Before=kubelet.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rkt api-service
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
RequiredBy=kubelet.service
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I wasn't clear enough regarding my etcd question. updated main post.

Comment: Added an issue regarding etcd tls at https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/issues/700

Comment: btw I checked and ADVERTISE_IP cannot have a domain, only an ip address.